# How to let maas' cloud-init client select internal mirror?

Tags: maas, cloud-init

Our maas LAN can't access the internet and has a internal apt-mirror site 192.168.3.6. I changed the mirror set of maas server's snippets/maas_proxy file as follows:

```
d-i     mirror/country string manual
d-i     mirror/http/hostname string 192.168.3.6
d-i     mirror/http/directory string /ubuntu
d-i     mirror/http/proxy string
```

I deployed two maas node. Dashboard show the two node's state are ready.
But node's cloud-init client changed the apt's sources.list like this:

```
## Note, this file is written by cloud-init on first boot of an instance
## modifications made here will not survive a re-bundle.
## if you wish to make changes you can:
## a.) add 'apt_preserve_sources_list: true' to /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg
##     or do the same in user-data
...
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
...
```

Directly use cobbler install node(without maas), the node apt's sources.list like:

```
...
deb http://192.168.3.6/ubuntu precise main
deb-src http://192.168.3.6/ubuntu precise main
...
```

My question is:

1. How to set user-data in maas? So that I can set cloud-init's mirror's url to 192.168.3.6 or prevent cloud-init to change mirror's url.
2. Maas node's file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys is empty. Is it caused by the mirror's setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, we can complete node installation by add a line in /var/lib/cobbler/snippets/maas_preseed like:

```
 $maas_preseed_data    
 cloud-init   cloud-init/local-cloud-config string manage_etc_hosts: localhost
+cloud-init   cloud-init/local-cloud-config string apt_preserve_sources_list: true
```

In factor, cloud-init/local-cloud-config is the cloud-init's local configer.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for reporting this.  I've opened [bug 1006966](https://bugs.launchpad.net/maas/+bug/1006966) against upstream maas to address this.

For the time being, the easiest way for you to work around this is probably to have a late_command install a file into /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg with content like:

```
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-local-mirror-only.cfg
apt_preserve_sources_list: true
```

Untested, but you may be able to accomplish that by doing:

```
--- /var/lib/cobbler/kickstarts/maas.preseed.dist   2012-05-31 15:37:06.689109923 +0000
+++ /var/lib/cobbler/kickstarts/maas.preseed    2012-05-31 15:37:43.293109690 +0000
@@ -90,4 +90,5 @@
 d-i    preseed/late_command string true && \
        $SNIPPET('maas_sudoers') && \
        $SNIPPET('maas_disable_pxe') && \
+       $SNIPPET('local_mass_local_mirror') && \
        true
--- /dev/null   2012-05-31 15:21:47.612623001 +0000
+++ /var/lib/cobbler/snippets/local_maas_local_mirror   2012-05-31 15:39:33.897110012 +0000
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+in-target sh -c "echo apt_preserve_sources_list: true > /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-local-mirror-only.cfg" \
```

Oh, and to answer "how to set userdata in maas", that is only currently possible by using the maas API.  There are no existing client tools at this time.

Comment: hi, smoser: I has tested your suggestion. Installer tip "Failed to run preseed command". And I found the boot of node has no /etc/cloud/ directory at that time.